# Logback - use more than one instance

Tags: java, android, kotlin, logback

I'm using logback in my Android project. I personally love this logger and not going to use anything else.

I started to use a GPS location and for that, I used a third party library '[background-geolocation-lt](https://github.com/transistorsoft/background-geolocation-lt)'. This library is also using a logback.

After background-geolocation-lt is loaded my logger stops working (not writing logs to file) and it seems that my configuration was overwritten by this library. Logcat and debug console loggin in proper way - it's all about file appenders. More details in code below - after initializing bgGeo the message "I'm not writing to file" hasn't been written to file.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainActivity::class.java)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // some other code

        logger.info("I'm writing to file")

        val bgGeo =
            BackgroundGeolocation.getInstance(applicationContext, intent)

        logger.info("I'm not writing to file")
    }
}
```

My config file is really simple:

```
<configuration>
<property name="LOG_DIR" value="${DATA_DIR}/logs" />

<appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
    <tagEncoder>
        <pattern>%logger{12}</pattern>
    </tagEncoder>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/current_log.txt</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

My question is:

**Is it possible to create a separated instance of logback with separated configuration and logger factory?**

Thanks in advance for any help in this subject :)

Answer (score 0):

try excluding transitive dependency of `logback` from `background-geolocation-lt` library, you can exclude any transitive dependency like this -

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.example.m:m:1.0') {
     exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'x 
  }
  compile 'com.example.l:1.0'
}
```

Just to make sure Logback is coming as indirect dependency you can check the dependency tree using -

```
gradle dependencies
```

Comment: The background-geolocation-lt is using the same version of logback as my application. Excluding it is causing the error. I used it like this:     implementation background_geolocation {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }